# Can you use Python relative imports to import the __init__ file of the current module under a specific name?

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

Imagine I have a module with two files, like this:

```
mymodule
 |-- __init__.py
 `-- submodule.py
```

`mymodule/__init__.py` contains:

```
SOME_CONSTANT_ONE = 1
SOME_CONSTANT_TWO = 2
SOME_CONSTANT_THREE = 3
...
SOME_CONSTANT_ONE_HUNDRED = 100

def initialize():
    pass # do some stuff

def support_function():
    pass # something that lots of other functions might need
```

I already know that I can use a relative import to bring in *specific* objects from the `__init__.py` file, like this:

submodule.py:

```
from . import initialize, support_function

def do_work():
    initialize() # initialize the module
    print(support_function()) # do something with the support function
```

But now what I want to know is if I can import *all* of the constants from the `__init__.py` file, but simultaneously have them appear in a namespace.

What won't work (what I've tried/considered):

- `import mymodule as outer_module` works, since the import system already has knowledge of where the module is. However, if I ever need to change the name of the outer module, that code will break.
- Doing `import . as outer_module` doesn't work.
- Doing `from . import *` does work but puts all of the objects in `__init__.py` in the current namespace rather than in the sub-namespace.
- Doing `from . import SOME_CONSTANT_ONE as outer_constant_1, SOME_CONSTANT_TWO as outer_constant_2, SOME_CONSTANT_THREE as outer_constant_3, ...` is ugly and won't bring in any new constants should they be defined later on in `__init__.py`.

What I *really* want is something like this:

submodule.py:

```
SOME_CONSTANT_ONE = "one!" # We don't want to clobber this.

import . as outer_module # this does not work, but it illustrates what is desired.

def do_work():
    print(SOME_CONSTANT_ONE)              # should print "one!"
    print(outer_module.SOME_CONSTANT_ONE) # should print "1"
```

I know that I could move all of the constants to a `constants.py` file and then I should be able to import it with `from . import constants (as something)` but I'm working on existing code and making that change would require a lot of refactoring. While that's not a bad idea, I'm wondering, given that Python does have a way to import individual objects, and also to import the whole module *by name* to an explicit name, if I can maybe do something with `importlib` to accomplish importing everything from `__init__.py` into a namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loader sets `__package__` which you can use:

```
import sys

SOME_CONSTANT_ONE = "one!" # We don't want to clobber this.

outer_module = sys.modules[__package__]

def do_work():
    print(SOME_CONSTANT_ONE)              # should print "one!"
    print(outer_module.SOME_CONSTANT_ONE) # should print "1"
```

This is precisely the attribute from which relative imports are based.
See [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for details.

However, I really think the backwards-compatible refactoring which the other answer suggests is probably the better approach here.

Answer (score 2):

> I could move all of the constants to a `constants.py` file and then I should be able to import it with `from . import constants (as something)` but I'm working on existing code and making that change would require a lot of refactoring

You can still refactor the constants into the new `constants.py` module. To support existing code relying on `__init__.py` you can import constants into the `__init__.py`

```py
# constants.py
SOME_CONSTANT_ONE = 1
SOME_CONSTANT_TWO = 2
SOME_CONSTANT_THREE = 3
... # etc
```

```py
# __init__.py
from .constants import *
```

```py
# submodule.py
SOME_CONSTANT_ONE = 'dont clobber me!'
from . import constants as something
print(something.SOME_CONSTANT_ONE) # Yay namespaces
```

```py
# existing_code.py
from . import SOME_CONSTANT_ONE
# still works!
# no refactor required!
```

*Typically* speaking, the `__init__.py` file is usually left completely empty and nothing is ever directly defined there. If there are contents in `__init__.py` they are typically imported from within the package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/5747944